# Edit column in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am just trying to edit some specific column in database, its one of my first try in PHP OPP and one of my first in PHP in general so please be patience

```
public function prepareEdit() {
  $id = $_GET ['id'] ;
  $con = new PDO (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $id";
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<input type='text' name='name' value=".$row['name'].">";
    echo "<input type='text' name='email' value=".$row['email'].">";
    echo "<input type='text' name='message' value=".$row['message'].">";
    echo "<input type='text' name='phone' value=".$row['phone'].">";
    echo "<input type='text' name='reason'>";
   }
  echo "<input type='submit' value='Odoslat' name='send'>";
}



public function edit(){
         $correct = false;
    try {
        $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "UPDATE user(name, email, phone, message) VALUES(:name, :email, :phone, :message)";

        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "name", $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "email", $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "phone", $this->phone, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "message", $this->message, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();
        return "Formular upraveny";
    }catch( PDOException $e ) {
    return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

And this is my edit.php file

```
<?php
    include_once("config.php");
    if( !(isset( $_GET['id'] ) ) ) {       
    $WebsiteUsers = new WebsiteUsers();
    $WebsiteUsers->renderAll();
    }    
else {
    $WebsiteUsers = new WebsiteUsers();
    $WebsiteUsers->prepareEdit();
     if( !(isset( $_POST['send'] ) ) ) {
            $WebsiteUsers = new WebsiteUsers();
            $WebsiteUsers->storeFormValues( $_POST );     
         }
}
?>
```

I have data in form its no problem, i press SUBMIT button to send them and no data is changed in database, can somebody help me to fix it?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you should include a `WHERE` in your update statement. Otherwise, you'll change every row.

Comment: @andrewsi you are right man, i forgot that, but its not fixing my problem because atm it dont upgrade anything

@AbhikChakraborty mate i am not sure if its requied to have `:` anyway i did try it with no change:(

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is incorrect:

`UPDATE user SET name = :name, email = :email, phone = :phone, message = :message WHERE user_id = 123`

Dont forget to modify the WHERE condition in the above SQL...

Comment: you are right mate, atleast i didnt have WHERE there, but it should still update everything in that table, i try your code but nothing happend there as well :(

Comment: yea mate i noticed that dots and edited it by my self before but it didnt help unfortunately

Comment: Try this to see if there is any PDO error: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php

Comment: Not throwing anything, i think problem will be in that i am not making right DB connection or not telling what to edit or idk :)